# Something wrong with as.mids from mice package in R?

Tags: r, multiple-imputation, mice

I am running some imputations using the mice package in R. During this process I need to use the as.mids function. However, it seems that as.mids change the values of my subsequent analysis - but I hope I am just doing something wrong.

An example:

Let's say I first impute 5 datasets.

```
imp1 <- mice(myData, m=5)
```

To prove my point, I want to duplicate "imp1" using the "complete" function followed by the "as.mids" function

```
#Creates a long/stacked dataframe from the 5 imputed datasets (+ original)
impData <- complete(imp1, "long", include = TRUE)

#The stacked dataframe is now converted to mids class named "imp2"
imp2 <- as.mids(impData)
```

Now, as I see it - both imp1 and imp2 should be identical. However, when I run an analysis and pool the data the results turn out to be different.

```
#Runs both analysis 
fit1 <- with(imp, lm(A ~ B + C + D))
fit2 <- with(imp2, lm(A ~ B + C + D))

#Pools data from both
pooled1 <- pool(fit1)
pooled2 <- pool(fit2)

#Get the results
round(summary(pooled1), 3)
round(summary(pooled2), 3)
```

Here are some examples from my data

```
#Results from imp1
              est    se      t       df     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  7.844  0.316  24.832   8.648    0.000  
B           -0.013  0.002  -5.193  10.587    0.000 
C            0.024  0.009   2.821  24.997    0.009  
D            0.248  0.139   1.785   9.425    0.106

#Results from imp2
              est    se      t       df     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  7.756  0.376  20.623   8.320    0.000  
B           -0.011  0.005  -2.361   5.800    0.058 
C            0.024  0.008   2.780  35.214    0.009  
D            0.229  0.140   1.637  11.967    0.128
```

As you can see, there are some differences. While these difference are not large, it is still unsettling because it indicates that I might have made some mistake or misunderstood something.

Is there someone who can explain why I get these results using as.mids function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed a bug somewhere in `as.mids`.

I used `as.mids` to convert a stacked dataset of 10 imputations, and then got a list of imputations from it.  Weird stuff would happen.  Once I randomly got `NA`s from a value.  Other times it started changing values in my final imputation.  It also calculated my standard errors wrong.

I then wrote a function:

```
getImpList <- function(MIdata, impIDColumn){
  d <- list()
  imps <- max(MIdata[,impIDColumn])
  for(i in 1:imps){
    d[[i]] <- MIdata[MIdata[,impIDColumn]==i,]
  }
  return(d)
}
```

and used:

```
imputationList(getImpList(MI_data, mi_j_col))
```

where `mi_j_col` is the column index of mi imputation ID variable.  Everything then worked fine.  I double checked R's calculations vs. Stata's using `mi estimate` and everything checked out.

Answer (score 1):

I also discovered this bug in mice.

My analysis: `as.mids` assumes that the `.imp` column is coded as a factor, and therefore subtracts `1` from the max to get the right number of imputations. But if it is not a factor – subtracting `1` will lose the last imputation. Furthermore, `1` is only subtracted the second time the number of imputations are calculated, which is the reason for the random content in the last imputation.

I have edited the original function and commented my changes:

```
as.mids2 <- function (data, .imp = 1, .id = 2) 
    {
      # paste added to get numerical value if .imp is factor
      ini <- mice(data[data[, .imp] == 0, -c(.imp, .id)], m = max(as.numeric(paste(data[, .imp]))), maxit = 0)
      names <- names(ini$imp)
          if (!is.null(.id)) {
            rownames(ini$data) <- data[data[, .imp] == 0, .id]
          }
          for (i in 1:length(names)) {
            # -1 removed and paste added to get numerical value if .imp is factor
            for (m in 1:(max(as.numeric(paste(data[, .imp]))))) {
              if (!is.null(ini$imp[[i]])) {
                indic <- data[, .imp] == m & is.na(data[data[, .imp] == 0, names[i]])
                ini$imp[[names[i]]][m] <- data[indic, names[i]]
          }
        }
      }
      return(ini)
    }
```

Comment: It appears that this may have been corrected in the most recent release of mice (2.25, 2015-11-09).  There is now some code that checks to see if `.imp` is a factor.